# Passing variable argument list to sprintf()

Tags: php, parameters, arguments, printf

I would like to write a function that (amongst other things) accepts a variable number of arguments and then passes them to sprintf().

For example:

```
<?php
function some_func($var) {
  // ...
  $s = sprintf($var, ...arguments that were passed...);
  // ...
}

some_func("blah %d blah", $number);
?>
```

How do I do this in PHP?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
function some_func() {
    $args = func_get_args();
    $s    = call_user_func_array('sprintf', $args);
}

// or

function some_func() {
    $args = func_get_args();
    $var  = array_shift($args);
    $s    = vsprintf($var, $args);
}
```

The `$args` temporary variable is necessary, because [`func_get_args`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php) cannot be used in the arguments list of a function in PHP versions prior to 5.3.

Comment: oh I didn't know about vsprintf. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for that vsprint(), I wish I could upvote you more

Answer (score 2):

Or better yet (and a bit safer too):

```
function some_func(string $fmt, ... $args) {
    $s = vsprintf($fmt, $args);
}
```

This is PHP 7.4, not sure if it works in earlier versions.

Answer (score 1):

use a combination of [`func_get_args`](http://php.net/func_get_args) and [`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/call_user_func_array)

```
function f($var) { // at least one argument
  $args = func_get_args();
  $s = call_user_func_array('sprintf', $args);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use $numargs = func_num_args();
and func_get_arg(i) to retrieve the argument

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list

basically, you declare your function as usual, without parameters, then you call func_num_args() to find out how many arguments they passed you, and then you get each one by calling  func_get_arg() or func_get_args(). That's easy :)